# getting error at intent while passing bytearray from activity to activity

Tags: android, android-intent

i need to send bytearray from activity to activity through intents.I wrote following code to send the data but in the first activity itself,at intent i am getting error.here is my code

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_VIDEO) {
            if (requestCode == PICK_VIDEO) {
                Uri selectedVideoUri = data.getData();
                filemanagerstring = selectedVideoUri.getPath();
                Log.d("gftfhg", "onActivityResult: (((((((()))))))))))5654");
                bytes = readBytesFromFile(filemanagerstring);
                Log.d("2222", "onActivityResult: nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn"+bytes);
                if (bytes != null) {
                    Log.d("qqqqq", "onActivityResult: converted"+bytes);
                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, VideoActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("uri",bytes);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting. And why do you want to transfer byte array through intent. You can also transfer the URI to the VideoActivity and then do the URI to byte array conversion there

Comment: Your byte array might become huge in size and it would not make sense to transfer that through intents.

Comment: because i want to convert the viddeo into bytearray in one activity and that byte array should transfer to another activity.In the second activity i again want to convert bytrarray to file.This is my requirement.

Comment: Are you using byte array in this activity anywhere? Are you using that bytearray in your second activity apart from writing into the file?

See i can understand the requirement that you need video array in one activity and write into a file in another but there shouldn't be a requirement that you need to transfer byte array from one activity to another. The only way this can work is if you transfer the URI or you create another file and transfer the path of that file to another activity.

Answer (score 1):

You should only pass limited data through intents between activities. My suggestion would be to pass the URI in your intent and then get the byte Array from URI in your second activity. This way your Video Activity will have all your video related code together as well.